# what is topic keyword in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I was analyzing one VIP, and found following line in it:

```
topic               class member;
```

Never seen such structure. 
Can someone please explain what "topic" means?

This is the code:

```
/*
    topic: AXI4STREAM VIP Package
    The package is systemverilog package for XILINX AXI4STREAM Verification Component IP, it includes all the classes,enums,
    typedefs etc. XILINX AXI4STREAM Verification Component IP has been developed to support the simulation of customer
    designed AXI-based IP.  Please refer PG277 for more details about this IP.
  */
   topic  AXI4STREAM VIP Package

  /*
    topic: class member
    <axi4stream_vif_proxy> `XIL_AXI4STREAM_PARAM_ORDER         vif_proxy; AXI4STREAM VIF Proxy Class. 
    <xil_analysis_port> #(axi4stream_monitor_transaction)      item_collected_port; provides methods to collect monitor transaction.
  */
  topic              class member;
```

This is part of free xilinx AXI VIP code

Answer (score 2):

There is no such reserved keyword in SystemVerilog. please show the surrounding code.

Update: this looks like it may be used by some other tool for documentation. You need to ask the people that wrote the code.

Comment: Updated the question description